# The return type 'Set<Text>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

The inner map function is causing the error in the title and I don't know how I can fix this. I want to make a calculation in the inner map function before returning the  Widget.

```
 var rowOnee = Column(children: [
      ...stampRows.map((i) => Row(
            children: [
              ...[0,1,2,3,4].map((i) => {
                return Text("hi");
              })
            ],
          ))
    ]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the correct way to write an [anonymous function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#anonymous-functions) in dart:

```dart
(i) => {
  return Text("hi");
}
```

You can either do:

```dart
(i) {
  return Text("hi");
}
```

or

```dart
(i) => Text("hi"),
```

Note that the anonymous function has either `=>` for single expression anonymous functions or `{}` for multiline anonymous functions, but not both.

When you have both, the `{}` is interpreted instead as a set literal.

That said, you really should use [collection-for](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) instead of combining `...` and `.map`. I suggest rewriting your code as the following:

```dart
var rowOnee = Column(children: [
  for (var i in stampRows)
    Row(children: [
      for (var i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) Text("hi")
    ]),
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to fix it. One way is to remove the arrow:

```
 var rowOnee = Column(children: [
      ...stampRows.map((i) => Row(
            children: [
              ...[0,1,2,3,4].map((i) {
                return Text("hi");
              })
            ],
          ))
    ]);
```

Or you could remove the curly brackets and return statement:

```dart
var rowOnee = Column(children: [
     ...stampRows.map((i) => Row(
           children: [
             ...[0,1,2,3,4].map((i) => Text("hi"))
           ],
         ))
   ]);
```